# get the teacher of specefic course using classrrom api

Tags: java, google-classroom

I'm trying to get the list of courses of a specefic teacher.
I did like that:

```
String courseId = "64294889578";
ListTeachersResponse response = service1.courses().teachers().list(courseId)
                    .setPageSize(100)
                    .setPageToken(pageToken2)
                    .execute();
```

I got that error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden {   "code" : 403,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
>       "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"   } ],   "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",   "status" :
>   "PERMISSION_DENIED" }     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1067)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>     at
>   se.edt.classroom.ClassroomQuickstart.main(ClassroomQuickstart.java:86)

So I tried changing the scope defined by

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
Collections.singletonList(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_GUARDIANLINKS_ME_READONLY);
```

to all existing **scopes** for example `CLASSROOM_COURSES`, but no success.

Have you please any idea about solving that ?.
Big thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the scope **CLASSROOM_ROSTERS**

HTH

#### Reference:

- [Classroom API: Scopes](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth#OAuth2Authorizing)